# C preprocessor: why extra space between token and result of # operator?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, c11

Sample code (t2.c):

```
#define T2(x)   M#x
#define T1(x)   T2(x)
T1(xxx)
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM= | grep xxx -w
"xxx"
$ gcc t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=1 | grep xxx -w
1"xxx"
$ gcc t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=L | grep xxx -w
L "xxx"  // <== why extra space ??
$ gcc t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=K | grep xxx -w
K "xxx"  // <== why extra space ??

$ clang t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM= | grep xxx -w
"xxx"
$ clang t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=1 | grep xxx -w
1"xxx"
$ clang t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=L | grep xxx -w
L "xxx"  // <== why extra space ??
$ clang t2.c -std=c11 -E -DM=K | grep xxx -w
K"xxx"   // <== why behavior for K is different from behavior for L ??

$ cl t2.c /std:c11 /E /DM= 2>&1 | grep xxx -w
"xxx"
$ cl t2.c /std:c11 /E /DM=1 2>&1 | grep xxx -w
1"xxx"
$ cl t2.c /std:c11 /E /DM=L 2>&1 | grep xxx -w
L "xxx"  // <== why extra space ??
$ cl t2.c /std:c11 /E /DM=K 2>&1 | grep xxx -w
K"xxx"   // <== why behavior for K is different from behavior for L ??
```

Versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0

clang --version
clang version 11.0.1
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

$ cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29913 for x64
```

Please help to understand the behavior and the difference.

Comment: `-E` output is something internal for the compiler, compiler can do what it wants. An answer to "why space" would be "see compiler sources". The space before `L` would most probably be because `L"xxx"` is a wide string literal and the next compiler processing stage needs to differentiate that, but that's a guess. Now try `-DM=u` or `-DM=U`.

Comment: The linked answer is about the space in `0x40E +20`, but the reasoning is the same: `L"..."` means something else.